# How to NSolve when an NIntegrate is involved?

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

I need to find the set of 3rd order polynomial coefficients that will give a bounded exponential function f(x) = Exp[ c0 + c1*x + c2*x^2 + c3*x^3] a set of specified 0th,1st,2nd,and 3rd order moments.

I knew this code here wouldn't actually work, but it expresses what I'm trying to do:

```
bound = 3;  (*limits of integration*)
moments = {1, 0, 1, 8};   (* desired values of moments of exponential funct*)
coeff = {c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3]};   (* polynomial coefficients*)
expr = {1, x, x^2, x^3}*Exp[Sum[c[j]*(x^j), {j, 0, 3}]];
calcMoments = NIntegrate[expr, {x, -bound, bound}];
NSolve[calcMoments == moments, coeff]
```

I implemented a routine to minimize a penalty function J = Total[(moments-calcMoments)^2] by random walk or gradient descent, but it was slow and homemade and I'd prefer to put Mathematica's sophisticated numerical optimization capabilities to use if that's possible here.  How might I do this?